# Android Library Issues

Tags: android, sdk, android-library

I am developping an app that I am always running on my nexus 7 with min SDK and SDK target on api 17.

From now, it always works.
But today I try to test my app on my cell phone which is on 4.0.

It is impossible to compile and install it on my phone and I have that log :

> error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'parentActivityName'
>   in package 'android'

After googeling, I figure out that it is because parentActivityName is only supported on API 16 and more. I read that it is still possible to make it works on lower api device when installing a support library.

So I download android support library v13 jar, put it on my folder Workspace\MyApp\libs, then I build the path from eclipse and still, my app is not working.

With min SDK 14 ( to try it on my phone ) , target 17 AND the support library on the path ( to be able to use the 'parentActivityName' thing with the support library V 13 ), impossible to compile !

Any ideas ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add the required `meta-data` tag. Here's a manifest from an [Android tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#CreateActivity) that covers this:

```
<application ... >
    ...
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: I do have that meta-data but as you can see on the link that you gave me :The android:parentActivityName attribute declares the name of this activity's parent activity within the app's logical hierarchy. The system uses this value to implement default navigation behaviors, such as Up navigation on Android 4.1 (API level 16) and higher. You can provide the same navigation behaviors for older versions of Android by using the Support Library and adding the <meta-data> element as shown here. /// That's why it is not running on my cell phone, which is 4,0 ( api lvl 15 )